# Python, numpy, matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

```
A=[['2' '7' 'fas']
 ['4' '8' 'sda']
 ['1' '5' 'daf']
 ['2' '24' 'gag']]
```

How can I get just matrix A, instead last "atribute" in each row:

```
A=[['2' '7']
 ['4' '8']
 ['1' '5' ]
 ['2' '24']]
```

I know that last element in row is [:-1]

I tried with numpy:

```
A[:,  ?? ]
```

**Matrix A is random elements, so I was thinking somethin in this way: `A[:,end-1]`, but numpy don't know what is end**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> arr=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> arr[:,:-1]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = [ ['2', '7', 'fas']
        , ['4', '8', 'sda']
        , ['1', '5', 'daf']
        , ['2', '24', 'gag']
        ]

>>> [ x[:-1] for x in A ]
[['2', '7'], ['4', '8'], ['1', '5'], ['2', '24']]
```